# Dump data frame values into a PostgreSQL table python

Tags: python-3.x, django, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have this data frame
[image]

I want to dump this data into a Postgres table which has a foreign key of supplier and origin how can I do that, note that all the information of a supplier and origin exists in another data frame.

Answer (score 0):

One of ways

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

SCHEMA_NAME = "schema_name"

def serialize_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, **kwargs) -> StringIO:
    kwargs.setdefault("index", False)
    kwargs.setdefault("sep", ",")
    kwargs.setdefault("quotechar", '"')
    kwargs.setdefault("date_format", "%d-%B-%Y")

    return StringIO(df.to_csv(**kwargs))

def copy_table(table_name: str, str_buffer: StringIO, conn=None):
    str_buffer.seek(0)
    header_row = str_buffer.readline().strip()

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(f'SET search_path TO "{SCHEMA_NAME}"')
        cur.copy_expert(
            f"""
            COPY "{table_name}" ({header_row}) FROM STDIN WITH
            (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', NULL '', HEADER false, QUOTE '"')
            """,
            str_buffer,
        )

def write_df_to_table(input_df: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str):
    data_buffer = serialize_dataframe(input_df)
    copy_table(table_name, data_buffer)
```

Comment: I already have the table created in DB

Comment: How you are inserting the foreign key data?

Comment: This example suppose that table already exists. What problem with foreign keys you mean?

Comment: can we take this into a chat room ?